# Query all items and ignore if condition

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I current have two functions which perform queries on my database; the first one performs a query on all my entries and the second has a specification (for version control).

*Database -> **edited***

```
id | version_id | post_id
-------------------------
1  |    1       |   1
2  |    2       |   2
3  |    1       |   1
4  |    1       |   1
```

*Code -> **edited***

```
public function post($postid)
{
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news";
    return $db->select($query);
}
public function version_count()
{
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE post_id='1' ORDER BY version_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    return $db->select($query);
}
```

To display my entries, I've tried the following, which does as expected, giving me all entries:

```
$posts_array = $query->post($post);
foreach ( $counted_versions as $post )
{
    echo $post->id . "-";
}
```

However, I only want to echo rows 2 and 4, since 2 is unique and 4 is the most recent.

At first, I thought this logic would work :

```
$posts_array = $query->post($post);
$counted_versions  = $query->version_count();

foreach ( $counted_versions as $counted )
{
    foreach ( $posts_array as $post )
    {
        echo $post->id . "-";
    }
}
```

But rather, I get `1-2-3-4-` and if I switch my foreach loops around, I get `4-4-4-4-`, whereas I would expect `2-4` or at the very least `1-4` (or `4-2` or `4-1`).

Anybody have a way to get a similar result?

Comment: What's `post_id`? Your table only has `id` and `version_id` columns.

Comment: Your description of your code doesn't match the code at all. The first query doesn't return all entries, it only returns the entry with `id=$postid`. And the second one should just return a single row because of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Why are you writing a nested loop? The outer loop iterates over rows, the inner loop iterates over the columns in the row.

Comment: So I've added the missing field (it actually is in my db) and corrected the query; however, I'm still wondering how I could loop through each `post_id` to find the highest value for `id` and make sure only the highest `id` value appears. Does this sound more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the highest `id` for each `post_id`, use the following query:

```
SELECT post_id, MAX(id) max_id
FROM news
GROUP BY post_id
```

Comment: So, working from this method, I now have `$query = "SELECT id, post_id, version_id, MAX(version_id) max_version_id FROM news GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY max_version_id DESC"` and my foreach calls upon `$version->version_id`, but I don't have the highest value for `version_id`, I have `1` as a result. Any idea why?

Comment: When you include non-aggregated columns in your query, it gets them from a random row in the group, not necessarily the row that contains `MAX(version_id)`. If you want to get the columns associated with the max, you need to join your original table with a subquery that gets the max.

Comment: My foreach loop goes like so: `foreach ( $version_array as $version ) {$id = $version->id; $newest = $version->version_id; echo $id . "/" . $newest ."<br />"; }`

Comment: If you want to know the max version ID for each post_id, use `$version->max_version_id, not `$version->version_id`.

Comment: ...and I'm overthinking again. Thanks a million!